# how to generate multiple .dll given multiple .obj with cl

Tags: c++, dll, cl

I know how dlls are generated using cl compiler. I first generate .obj and then generate .dll as follows

```
cl /c add.cpp  
link /DLL add.obj
```

My question is how can I generate multiple .dll given multiple .obj? I've tried the following two methods with no luck

```
link /DLL add.obj sub.obj
link /DLL /OUT:add.dll /OUT:sub.dll add.obj sub.obj
```

Comment: Use a batch script and a loop

Comment: @RyanJ, I'm not familiar with batch script, but I can write c++ code to achieve this goal. The weird thing is that with `lib` command I can generate multiple libs given multiple .obj but I can't do the same with dll.